# Java : how does weakhashmap determine if the key is 'obsolete' or not?

Tags: java, weakhashmap

How does it know this key is old and ready to throw it away ? and why string literal ?

For example,

```
  private static WeakHashMap<<? extends Object>, String> m = 
                             new WeakHashMap<<? extends Object>, String>();

  public static void A(){

       Point p = new Point();
       m.put(p, "a");

  }
```

does it mean that 'p' key will be gone as soon as A() returns ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WeakHashMap` doesn't make that determination; rather, the normal Java garbage collection process deletes unreferenced keys.  The `p` key will be gone as soon as Java garbage collection is triggered.

What `WeakHashMap` does is it uses weak references to refer to keys, so the garbage collector knows not to count the `WeakHashMap` references to the map keys as "holding" the key objects in memory.

Comment: Makes sense...but why string literal /

Comment: What do string literals have to do with it?

Comment: like using string key = "something" instead of string key = new string("something").

Comment: How is that related to `WeakHashMap`?  Weak references only care about reference equality, so `new String("something")` will get GC'd separately from `"something"`, but that's part of why `String` isn't often appropriate to use for a `WeakHashMap` key.

Comment: By the way..this might be unrelated...how often does gc get triggered ?

Comment: GC gets triggered in response to memory pressure: after enough allocation happens that the program needs to free up some memory.  You can explicitly encourage it yourself, but it's a bad idea to depend on GC happening at any particular point.